# Show $ (xyz+1) \left ( \frac{1}{x^2+x}+\frac{1}{y^2+y}+\frac{1}{z^2+z} \right ) \ge 3$ with $x,y,z >0$

Tags: inequality

Prove that for $x,y,z >0 $ the following inequalities hold :

$$ 3(xyz+1) \left ( \frac{1}{x^2+x}+\frac{1}{y^2+y}+\frac{1}{z^2+z} \right ) \ge 9 $$

$$ (xyz+1) \left ( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{1}{z+1} \right ) \ge 9  $$

Actually, the first inequality allows us to show the second one since it lower-bounds it.

Comment: Are you (a friend of) [math110](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/58742/math110)? If not, you should meet.

Comment: I don't know him, why should I meet him ?

Comment: Ok, I will. But Now I need an idea about those two inequalities please.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is cyclic in $x, y$ and $z$, and therefore the function obtained by setting $y = z = x$ contains a stationary point. Note that $(x, y, z)\to(0, 0, 0)$ sends the left side to infinity, so it must be a minimum. By locating the minimum of this single-variable function, we locate the minimum of the multi-variable one. The left hand side is:
$$
f(x)=\frac{9(x^3 + 1)}{x^2 + x} =\frac{9(x+1)(x^2 - x + 1)}{x(x+1)}=9\left(x + \frac{1}{x}-1\right)
$$ 
Then, by using $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^n=(1-x)^{-1}$, we have:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n=\frac{1}{x}\implies\frac{1}{x}\approx1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2\geq1+(1-x)
$$
And therefore, $f(x) \geq 9\left(x - 1 + [1+(1-x)] \right)=9$

Comment: Why did you set $x=y=z$ ?

Comment: @Gogola As I said, because the inequality is cyclic. Interchanging any two variables results in the same expression, so it can't possible "favor" any of them.

Comment: So we can do that everytime that we have a cyclic inequality ?

Comment: @Gogola Cyclic inequalities always have stationary points when all variables are equal, but the point may be a max, min, or inflection. You need do do a little more work to figure out which one of those it is.

Comment: Mr.G, what about the following? For non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a+b+c=3$ prove that: $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\leq4$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In that case, $a = b = c$ is an inflection point, so the method I used is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

$(xyz+1) \left ( \dfrac{1}{x^2+x}+\dfrac{1}{y^2+y}+\dfrac{1}{z^2+z} \right ) \ge 3  \iff x^3 y^3 z+x^3 y^2 z+x^3 y z^3+x^3 y z^2+x^2 y^3 z-3 x^2 y^2 z^2-2 x^2 y^2 z+x^2 y^2+x^2 y z^3-2 x^2 y z^2-3 x^2 y z+x^2 y+x^2 z^2+x^2 z+x y^3 z^3+x y^3 z^2+x y^2 z^3-2 x y^2 z^2-3 x y^2 z+x y^2-3 x y z^2-3 x y z+x y+x z^2+x z+y^2 z^2+y^2 z+y z^2+y z \ge 0 \iff (y^2 z+x z^2+x^2 y-3 x y z)+(x y^2 z^3+x^2 z^2+y z-3 x y z^2)+(x^2 y^3 z+y^2 z^2+x y-3 x y^2 z)+(x^3 y z^2+x^2 y^2+x z-3 x^2 y z)+(x^3 y^2 z+x^2 y z^3+x y^3 z^2-3 x^2 y^2 z^2)+[x^2z+yz^2+xy^2+(x^3 y^3 z-2 x^2 y^2 z)+(x^3 y z^3-2 x^2 y z^2)+(x y^3 z^3-2 x y^2 z^2)] \ge 0 \iff F1+F2+F3+F4+F5+[3xyz+(x^3 y^3 z-2 x^2 y^2 z)+(x^3 y z^3-2 x^2 y z^2)+(x y^3 z^3-2 x y^2 z^2)] \ge 0 \iff F1+F2+F3+F4+F5+F6+F7+F8 \ge 0 $

$F1=y^2 z+x z^2+x^2 y-3 x y z \ge 0 , "=" hold \ when \ y^2 z=x z^2=x^2 y$

$F2=x y^2 z^3+x^2 z^2+y z-3 x y z^2 \ge 0, "=" hold \ when \ x y^2 z^3=x^2 z^2=y z $

$F3=x^2 y^3 z+y^2 z^2+x y-3 x y^2 z \ge0 ,"=" hold \ when \ x^2 y^3 z=y^2 z^2=x y$

$F4=x^3 y z^2+x^2 y^2+x z-3 x^2 y z \ge 0, "=" hold \ when \ x^3 y z^2=x^2 y^2=x z $

$F5=x^3 y^2 z+x^2 y z^3+x y^3 z^2-3 x^2 y^2 z^2 \ge 0, "=" hold \ when \ x^3 y^2 z=x^2 y z^3=x y^3 z^2 $

$F6=x^3 y^3 z+xyz-2 x^2 y^2 z \ge 0 ,"=" hold \ when \ x^3 y^3 z=xyz $

$F7=x^3 y z^3+xyz-2 x^2 y z^2 \ge 0 , "=" hold \ when \ x^3 y z^3=xyz$

$F8=x y^3 z^3+xyz-2 x y^2 z^2 \ge 0 ,"=" hold \ when \ x y^3 z^3=xyz $

also to get $3xyz$ for $F6,7,8$. we have:$ x^2z=yz^2=xy^2$

$F1$ to $F8$ are all ture by AM-GM.

to make LHS$=0$, ie, $F1$ to $F8=0$, we must have $x=y=z=1$.

QED

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, it's obvious that for the both inequalities there is $f$,

for which we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$ and $f$ is a concave function.

Since the concave function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$,

it's enouth to prove the both inequalities for $y=x$,

which gives a polynomial degree three of $z$ and the rest is a lot of smooth work.